# Booking form creation

Tags: php, sql

Example:

I have an Hotel and need to build a form, where I can see rooms, which are not taken at given time.

Single Bookins are saved in an SQL Database Table:

```
room      start         end
1         2017-09-01    2017-09-10
2         2017-09-12    2017-09-15
1         2017-09-01    2017-09-10
```

---

Now I need all rooms, where a customer can get a room from 2017-09-10 to 2017-09-11 for example.

I tried to build a SQL query like:

```
SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE room_id NOT IN (
      SELECT room_id FROM bookings WHERE start <= #startTime# AND end >= #endTime#
)
```

But the result is not reliable. I think, I am not the first person to ask this, but I can not find any information with Dr. Google.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't have data with your conditions:

```
DECLARE @Rooms TABLE (Room_Id INT, Room VARCHAR(50) );
DECLARE @Bookings TABLE (Room_Id INT, StartDate DATE, EndDate DATE);

/**/
INSERT INTO @Rooms VALUES
(1,'Room1'),
(2,'Room2'),
(3,'Room3');

INSERT INTO @Bookings VALUES
(1,         '2017-09-01',    '2017-09-10'),
(2,         '2017-09-12',    '2017-09-15'),
(1,         '2017-09-01',    '2017-09-10');

SELECT *
FROM @Rooms
WHERE Room_Id NOT IN (SELECT Room_Id FROM @Bookings WHERE StartDate <= '2017-09-12' AND EndDate >= '2017-09-15' );
```

Result:

```
+=========+=======+
| Room_Id | Room  |
+=========+=======+
|       1 | Room1 |
+---------+-------+
|       3 | Room3 |
+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are very close. You are currently grabbing all rooms where the start of the booking is before or equal to your start time and the end of the booking is greater than or equal to your end time. While this works, it does not cover reservations that begin during the specified reservation time, nor does it cover reservations that end during the specified reservation time.

In order to catch these entries you simply need to switch the order of your variables in your argument. You want to check for bookings that begin before your end time, and those that end after your start time. This will cover any reservation that overlap the period you are searching for.

```
DECLARE @start DATE = '2017-09-11',
        @end DATE = '2017-09-13'

SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE room_id NOT IN (
      SELECT room_id FROM bookings WHERE start <= @end AND end >= @start
)
```

---

If, for example, you have the following values:

```
room      start         end
1         2017-09-01    2017-09-10
2         2017-09-12    2017-09-15
1         2017-09-01    2017-09-10
3         2017-09-09    2017-09-12
4         2017-09-14    2017-09-17
5         2017-09-13    2017-09-17
```

And your query uses `@start = '2017-09-11'` and `@end = '2017-09-13'`

The following rooms will be valid (assuming 5 rooms as shown above): `1, 4`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Removed `Sub Query`

```
SELECT R.* 
FROM @Rooms R, @Bookings B
WHERE R.room_id <> B.room_id
AND B.StartDate <= '2017-09-12'AND B.EndDate >= '2017-09-15'

--Using Inner Join
SELECT R.* 
FROM @Rooms R
INNER JOIN @Bookings B ON R.room_id <> B.room_id
WHERE B.StartDate <= '2017-09-12'AND B.EndDate >= '2017-09-15'
```

Comment: Try use joins instead of old way

Comment: @Sami Edited the Answer using Inner Join.